# I'm new to javascript so please explain me this program

Tags: javascript

```
// Week05: collections.js 
// Script to demonstrate using the links collection. 

   function processLinks()
        {

     var linksList = document.links; // get the document's links

      var contents = "<ul>";

      for ( var i = 0; i < linksList.length; ++i )
   {

          var currentLink = linksList[ i ];
          contents += "<li><a href='" + currentLink.href + "'>" + 
            currentLink.innerHTML + "</li>";
   } // end for

       contents += "</ul>";
       document.getElementById( "links" ).innerHTML = contents;
} 

window.addEventListener( "load", processLinks, false );
```

Comment: Instead of down-voting, maybe the "elitists" should ask some questions of someone who is self-proclaimed "new" to Javascript.

Comment: @ElGuapo, agree.
Anyways, open up console and type document.links. Its a collection of a tags inside the document. This script loops through those links and generates a list of a tags and appends them to an element whose's id is "links"

Comment: @ElGuapo - I agree that people can be a bit quick to vote down questions from newcomers, but while I didn't vote on this one I'd suggest that "Here is some code, what does it do?" isn't really the best of questions for the Stack Overflow format. (Although I did vote on your answer because I liked it.)

Answer (score 1):

Start with `window.addEventListener` this is listening for the load event of the window (in this case the DOM). Once the DOM is loaded it calls the function `processLinks`.

`processLinks` grabs all of the links in the DOM and creates an unordered list `<ul>` of them all and adds them to a DOM element with the id of "links".

Comment: Beat me by 40 seconds!